# bxslider wont stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider, jquery-waypoints

I am having an issue where the slider will not stop auto play when I click a link on my navigation menu. I start the slider via:

```
$('.bxslider1').bxSlider({auto: true,autoControls: true});
```

It auto plays and works, but if I try to stop the slider by creating an onclick function or .click() jQuery like:

```
$(".nav-portfolio").click(function() {
  slider = $('.bxslider1').bxSlider();
  slider.stopAuto();
});
```

It seems to do something for a split second and then start again. The reason I need to stop the slider is, I am using jQuery waypoints for anchor links to scroll smooth horizontally, and the panels start moving back and fourth by 1 or 2 pixels and its really annoying for the user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code to be:

```
$(".nav-portfolio").click(function() {
  $('.bxslider1').stopAuto();
});
```

You were previously using the example from the bxSlider webpage which assumes you haven't already initialized the bxSlider. Since you previously initialized it perhaps the second initialization isn't handled gracefully.

Comment: with my method it comes up in error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'stopAuto' of undefined, with your method: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stopAuto', you can check my site here for details [link](http://dev.ti-fund.com);

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `var` keyword before the `slider` declaration.

```
$(".nav-portfolio").click(function() {
   var slider = $('.bxslider1').bxSlider();
   slider.stopAuto();
});
```